# SQL Append/Union with different Column Counts and Column Names

Tags: sql, sql-server

I receive two data sets every month, one with 160 Columns of invoice data, one with 5 Columns of Forecast Data. 4/5 of the Forecast data columns match Columns in the invoice data (though the column names do not always match). One column is forecast volume which has no match in the invoice data.

I am trying to append these tables on top of each other, creating a new table with 161 Columns (the new column being forecast volume). Can I Union two tables in this way? perhaps by creating a new table with a null column and assigning the forecast volume to that null column?

Note: I tried a join based on the matching columns but this did not work because every material forecast is set to a specific date where we will order new material and there are therefore multiple forecast values for every single material code. In a join every invoice was then assigned either all the forecast volume or none.

Comment: You can do union as you said as long as all the columns that do have matches are the same data types and same names.  Then the ones that dont have a match you can do select cast(NULL as columndatatype) as ColumnName  from the one that does not have that column in it.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, yes you can.

```
SELECT col1, col2, col3, ..., col160, NULL AS forecast_volume
FROM invoice_data
UNION
SELECT col1, col2, col3, ..., col5, forecast_volume
FROM forecast_data;
```

btw column order and data types in both tables must match

Comment: And the number of columns must be the same.

Comment: Quick follow up, so if the matching columns are for example, 4,45,66,78 in the invoice data, do I have to move them all to the first 4 for the order to match? and thank you, now to figure out how to select all 160 columns, hopefully there's a way to not type them all out.

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**

Answer (score 0):

It is better for you to find a common field and join. If you can't, you can use union and cross join

If you want the table to be created in the following form, if it is empty in the equivalent of another table, we use union

```
SELECT invoice.Id,Name,family,t1,null DataS FROM invoice 
UNION ALL
SELECT null Id,null  Name,null  family,null t1, DataS FROM forecast
```

cross apply

| Id | Name | family | t1 | DataS |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | aa | bb | 1 | aadd |
| 2 | asda | bdsdb |  | 3 |
| 3 | cc | tt | 12 | aadd |
| 1 | aa | bb | 1 | assdsdda |
| 2 | asda | bdsdb | 3 | assdsdda |
| 3 | cc | tt | 12 | assdsdda |
| 1 | aa | bb | 1 | cdddc |
| 2 | asda | bdsdb | 3 | cdddc |
| 3 | cc | tt | 12 | cdddc |

But if you want it to be as below and the columns of two tables are multiplied together, use Cross apply

```
select invoice.Id,Name,family,t1,'' DataS from invoice 
cross apply( select * from forecast )a
```

Union all

| Id | Name | family | t1 | DataS |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | aa | bb | 1 | NULL |
| 2 | asda | bdsdb | 3 | NULL |
| 3 | cc | tt | 12 | NULL |
| NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | aadd |
| NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | assdsdda |
| NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | cdddc |

Base Data:

1.invoice:

| Id | Name | family | T1 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | aa | bb | 1 |
| 2 | asda | bdsdb | 3 |
| 3 | cc | tt | 12 |

2.forecast

| Id | DataS |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | aadd |
| 2 | assdsdda |
| 3 | cdddc |